# Why won't my script add anything to my number value? Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

All I am trying to do is add 50 onto my numbervalue. I have tried to print the current value out but it wont print either.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Status = game.ReplicatedStorage.PlayerPetStats.Stats2Clone --The petstat Folder of values
local foldernameloc = game.ReplicatedStorage.PlayerPetStats --Pet Stat folder
local PlayerName = " " -- Player name: is filled in with playeradded
local PlayerFolder = foldernameloc:FindFirstChild(PlayerName) --Finds players personal stats folder


PlayerFolder.Thirst.Value = PlayerFolder.Thirst.Value + 50
```

This script is in serverscriptservice and the values are in replicated storage. I don't know if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: Where is the `PlayerFolder` variable defined?

Comment: There is no error message apart from the fact it does not add @brance and ive just updated the question and added all of the places i have. the values are all in the replicated storage and have a duplicated folder names ( player.Name )